# Como fazer scroll automatico para uma distancia do top sem ancoragem Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rolamento

Bom já pesquisei bastante, vi diversos tutorias de como fazer um scroll via ancoragem, porem eu busco um scroll para todas as paginas inclusive a inicial, busquei alguns plugins no Wordpress como por exemplo: scroll in id, mas todos que achei cumprem a mesma ação me levar a determinado id...

> Preciso chegar a distancia do topo de 400, se fosse possivel fazer via
>   jquery faria assim:

```
$("body").scrollTop(400);
```

**Mas como fazer isso no Wordpress?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi vc quer que ao entrar na página ela role 400px. Se for isso vc pode usar o código abaixo. Eu tb inclui um `scroll-behavior: smooth;` para a rolagem ser um pouco mais lenta. Mas se vc não quiser esse efeito basta tira o CSS.

Basta clicar em executar abaixo para ver funcionando

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(400);
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f00 0%, #00f 100%);
    height: 200vh;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

[Resposta similar no site em inglês com outras opções de código jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html)

Comment: Mas como adiciono ele no wordpress? tentei adicionar diretamente ao fonte não consegui.

Comment: Seu WP já tem jQuery? Acredito que seja dentro do Function.PHP  ou de HEAD, isso depende de cada Tema... Se vc tiver acesso ao Footer.php coloque dentro do footer que é o ideal. Se puder vai na documentação do tema que está usando e pesquise por como adicionar scripts extra